# How to temporarily disable a single TButtonCategory?

Tags: delphi, vcl, delphi-10.4-sydney

In a Delphi 10.4.2 VCL Application, I have a `TCategoryButtons` object, containing several `Categories` (`TButtonCategory`). Unfortunately, `TButtonCategory` has not an `Enabled` property:

```
CategoryButtons1.Categories[0].Enabled := False; // undeclared identifier
```

So how can I temporarily disable a single `TButtonCategory` Category while leaving the other `Categories` enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Category buttons (TButtonItem) have no Visible property as well as no Enabled property. They are always visible and enabled. This extends to the TButtonCategory, which is also always visible and enabled, but you can collapse it.

Comment: Collapsing a Category does not prevent the user from expanding it.

Comment: Yes, the options to achieve what you want are minimal.

Comment: The individual buttons are not dervived from TWinControl - this is a single TWinControl that supports all buttons.  So the normal options for TButtons are not there.

Comment: It seems the only option is to modify the source code.

Comment: @user1580348 No: you could use a different control or reconsider your reasons to disabling, if not work around it. I'm interested in what made you choose it over others and now come up with such a requirement that was not part of your decision - is this control too new to you?

Comment: @AmigoJack Your assumptions are unlogical.

Answer (score 0):

Could you put them on a panel and change the visible property on that? Would have to test this locally, but may be a work around?